# Google Blogger: How to use <a></a> for internal links within a page

Tags: html, google-chrome

New to HTML5

Learn  for anchor links in a page

This is
[HTML I am using but fails to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOOXE.jpg)
see the result: http://obd2-diag.blogspot.com/2017/12/test.html
not working?

Could you please tell me what's the problem and how to solve?
Thanks in advance

Edit:
**the HTML sometimes works but sometimes not.**
i mean, the anchor links works in my laptop, while my friends says it never works
when click on "Go to Option 1" or "Go to Option 2", the page flash for a second then nothing different
seems Google blogger cannot work good with anchor link?

another question:
**can i use "name=xxx" instead of "id=xxx"?**
what's the difference?

again, thanks a lot

B.R.
Laura

Comment: Such as: `<a href="page.html">clickme</a>`

Comment: Your above code should be working correctly. I can't check your external link due to filter policies, but can confirm that the code your share in your image works correctly in and of itself. Something else must be interfering.